# Error: Script could not be translated from: null"

Tags: tradingview-api

Hi I am new to pine script and i am trying the below code. But always i am getting the Error "Script could not be translated from: null". Please to solve it

```
/@version=5
strategy("Pair Trade: Inputs")

longTrigger = input(title="% Change for short entries", defval=12)
shortTrigger = input(title="% Change for long entries", defval=12)

longTrigger := 1 - longTrigger/100
shortTrigger := 1 + shortTrigger/100

#google_close = request.security("GOOG", "D", close)
#google_open = request.security("GOOG", "D", open)

price_change = close / open

if price_change < longTrigger
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 5000)

if price_change > shortTrigger
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, 5000)
    
plot(price_change)
```

I tried to different ways but still not working